# Adding multiple ARM toolchains to path

Tags: linux, gcc, path, arm

So I am aiming to compile armv2 32 bit on my Mac such that it does not use the FP register which I have been told was not in earlier versions of arm 32 by my instructor.

I am thinking that if I use an earlier version of the toolchain it might support armv2 so while I currently have gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major added to path I might also add gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2018-q4-major to path.

Heres the issue both of them have the binary arm-none-eabi-gcc in them which is what I want to use and if I add both to my path... I am not sure how to specify whether to use 2019-q4 or 2018-q4's version of gcc. Any good ideas on how to set this up?

Also as a bonus if anyone knows how to force compile as armv2 that would be useful too so I can see if earlier versions did not use fp. Thankyou!

Comment: using the frame pointer is a command line option/setting, took a second to google that command line option and a few more to try it.  as for armv2 support was dropped by gcc/gnu.   2019-q4 doesnt mean much that is someones binary distribution, what does arm-whatever-gcc --version show that version is what matters.

Comment: you can find and download the arm2 docs as well to confirm or deny what you are being told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your tools will tell you everything you need to know, no need to use SO.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c -march=armv2a so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized -march target: armv2a
arm-none-eabi-gcc: note: valid arguments are: armv4 armv4t armv5t armv5te armv5tej armv6 armv6j armv6k armv6z armv6kz armv6zk armv6t2 armv6-m armv6s-m armv7 armv7-a armv7ve armv7-r armv7-m armv7e-m armv8-a armv8.1-a armv8.2-a armv8.3-a armv8.4-a armv8.5-a armv8-m.base armv8-m.main armv8-r iwmmxt iwmmxt2; did you mean ‘armv4’?
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -march=armvxx so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-march=armvxx’
arm-none-eabi-gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-march=’ are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m armv7ve armv8-a armv8-a+crc iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
```

so somewhere between 5.4.0 and 9.2.0 gcc dropped support for armv2 I suspect it was 6.x.x but the release notes from gcc is where to look.

google

```
gcc no frame pointer
```

and you find

```
-fomit-frame-pointer
-fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

test it

```
unsigned int test ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

arm-none-eabi-gcc -S -march=armv2 so.c

```
@ Function supports interworking.
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
@ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
@ link register save eliminated.
str fp, [sp, #-4]!
```

now this builds unusable code because it uses bx lr, so maybe gcc 5.x.x is no good either.  but to continue

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -S -march=armv2 so.c

test:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [sp, #4]
```

you can try this for armv4 and newer too gcc 5.x.x appears to default to using the frame pointer

9.2.0 is also using the frame pointer by default but the -fomit-frame-pointer option also works

(I intentionally didnt optimize as that would not use the stack, would have had to create a different test function that forced the use of the stack and a desire for a frame).

```
unsigned int another_test ( unsigned int );
unsigned int test ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(another_test(a)<<b);
}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -S -march=armv7-a so.c

test:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, lr}

arm-none-eabi-gcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 -S -march=armv7-a so.c

test:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, r5, fp, lr}
    add fp, sp, #12
```

same/similar results with optimization and an older version of gcc where it determined it didnt need a frame and didnt use one by default but if you forced it it would.

Comment: So does this mean that arm32 toolchains do not generate valid arm32 assembly without the -fno-omit-frame-pointer argument? Or that fp is indeed a register in arm32 assembly?